# Can not use AREarthManager.CheckVpsAvailability()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

In Geospatial API documentation, says

*Check VPS availability in your app
The Geospatial API can be used in any place where the device is able to determine its location. If your AR experience hinges on VPS coverage, you can use [AREarthManager.CheckVpsAvailability()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity-arf/class/Google/XR/ARCoreExtensions/AREarthManager#checkvpsavailability) to obtain a VpsAvailabilityPromise, an asynchronous task that checks the VPS availability at a given horizontal position. Once you have the VpsAvailabilityPromise, you can obtain its result by polling.*

But I can't use it. It doesn't exist. I know that this is static func...

I need to check if VPS is enabled or not. I just wonder why the function described in the official documentation doesn't exist.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do it's add this line of code at the top of your file:

```
using Google.XR.ARCoreExtensions;
```

After that you can use AREarthManager in your code, so for use that function you have to do this:

```
AREarthManager.CheckVpsAvailability(latitude, longitude);
```

Where latitude and longitude are a double variable where you want to check if vps is available